# iOS Can't set background image to tableview properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to set a background image to my menu tableView, or view at least.

I am able to set the background image but the imageView is offSet from the view

My tableview have the following constraints to the view:
- Equal width
- Equal height
- Align center X
- Align center Y

I tried to set the background image by diferent way :

1) In storyboard by adding an imageView to the background of the tableview with the same constraints

2) By coding :

First :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.menuTableView.frame = self.view.frame;

    self.menuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.menuTableView.delegate = self
    self.menuTableView.dataSource = self;
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView( image : UIImage(named:"background.png")!);
    backgroundImageView.frame = self.view.frame;

    self.menuTableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;
}
```

Second :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.menuTableView.delegate = self
    self.menuTableView.dataSource = self;

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"background.png")!);
    self.menuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
}
```

Third :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.menuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    self.menuTableView.delegate = self
    self.menuTableView.dataSource = self;

    self.parentViewController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"background.png")!);
    self.menuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
}
```

And the result is already the same :

[image: Menu screen shot]

As you can see, there are offsets to the left and bottom part of the view..
The expected result is that the image fill the view.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: set `backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: Ok with ScaleAspectFill, not with ScaleAspectFit, but i already have a bottom offset, is it due to the image height?

Comment: try to add imageView as subview like this, self.tableView.backgroundView?.addSubview(yourImageView)

Comment: That is a direction for you, maybe you should also try other modes. And there might be other options that need to be set. I am not able to answer it specifically with your question content though.

Comment: Please attach image used.